# cassandra insert and update

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cassandra

my cassandra database has a columns called "createdClientId" and "updateClientId". my model class has a fields called id(primary_key), createdClientId and updateClientId. My request is a post request  which has a client-id as a header and that client id needs to be value of  columns "createdClientId" and "updateClientId" at the time of insertion and while updating it should update only "updateClientId"

my dao looks like this

```
public void getdata(Model model, String clientId) {
        model.setcreatedClientId(clientId);
        model.setupdateClientId(clientId);
        String insert = SimpleJson.writeValueAsString(model);
        // insert query
String query = PropertyManager.getProperty("prop") + insert + "' IF NOT EXISTS;";
ResultSet rs = cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().queryForResultSet(query);
        if (rs != null) {
            LOGGER.log(DEBUG, "Result set is not null");
            if (rs.wasApplied()) {
                response.setMessage(RESPONSE_MESSAGE + " Created successfully");
            } else if (!rs.wasApplied()) {
                model.setUpdatedBy(clientId);
                // update query
                query = PropertyManager.getProperty("prop") + insert + "'";
                cassandraTemplate.getCqlOperations().queryForResultSet(query);
                response.setMessage(RESPONSE_MESSAGE + " Updated successfully");
            }
        }
    }
```

now when i am inserting data it works fine(ie both createdClientId & updateClientId fields are saving with same values of client-id) but when i update  it should only update updateClientId instead it is updating the createdClientId also which it should not.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `createdClientId` is also updated every time is that this line
`model.setupdateClientId(clientId);` is executed every time, then you create insert string
 `String insert = SimpleJson.writeValueAsString(model);` and using this string in both cases, so `createdClientId` get updated. 
One solution is to separate your data into two separate Cassandra tables: one that persists `createdClientId` piece of data for only one time and another table to support your frequent updates that holds `updatedClientId` (both with `clientId` as primary key) and use `'IF NOT EXISTS'` with first table queries.
The drawback here is that you have to make two requests to Cassandra for each of your post requests but the one for the first table should be executed only once if you use `'IF NOT EXISTS'`